# python lxml printing empty list

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, lxml

This piece of code prints `[]` each time. I've checked via firepath and manually, and the xpath expression is correct.

```
source = requests.get('http://example.com').text
x = source.encode('ascii', 'ignore') #for html entities
print [p for p in fromstring(x).xpath('/html/body/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[4]/td/div/div[1]/form/input[9]')]
```

Comment: Show the relevant html part that contains the input you are trying to get, or share a link to the web-site. We need to see what you are really querying, we cannot guess.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=HydwqC9K Thanks

Comment: The auth code (it's in 2 spots, doesn't matter which)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the `input` by the `name` attribute and get the value of `value` attribute:

```
import lxml.html

tree = lxml.html.fromstring(source)
print tree.xpath('//input[@name="auth"]/@value')[0]
```

prints: `AzfnTz624V0WmSiezU5U2TmtPo-...`

Comment: I guess I must be seeing things :D